# I'm trying to get a basic React Native setup going but there's a problem connecting with Watchman

Tags: react-native, watchman

I'm taking a course on React Native but can't seem to get my workflow going. I've installed everything as described in the 'Getting Started' docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started).
I can use Xcode and Android Studio to get the simulator / virtual device running - I have no problems with that; I can also build the project fine using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`. But when that script runs it brings up a new terminal that tries to run Watchman, and I get the following errors: 
`Loading dependency graph...2019-08-10T18:23:46,363: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/learning-state/sock! (No such file or directory)

Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2019-08-10T18:23:46,363: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/learning-state/sock! (No such file or directory)`

The sock! file is indeed not there, and if I add it with `touch` the error message doesn't change.
I have also tried uninstalling/reinstalling watchman, and modifying permissions to the folder (`chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/run/watchman/<NAME>-state`, where  is my username).

I've seen the question at https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/711 - my issue is slightly different in that I never had it working in the first place.

One thing I'm a little suspicious of is that I'm running two users on this MacBook - it's my work laptop, and I created a personal user for learning. It is in this personal user that I'm getting the issues. The only other unusual behavior I had with two users on one machine was that Homebrew had me move access to it from one user to the other in order to use it - I have to switch back and forth. Both users are admins.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or at least know what I should be expecting out of the sock! file? I'm running macOS Mojave, I've tried React Native 0.59 (first) and then 0.60, with Watchman 4.9.0. Barring that, does anyone have any suggestions on how to get a React Native workflow going without watchman?

EDIT:
@Jeff, you were right about the exclamation point. If I create a blank file there called `sock` instead, the error changes to this: `Loading dependency graph...2019-08-13T17:40:40,581: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on /usr/local/var/run/watchman/learning-state/sock! (Socket operation on non-socket)`

Comment: Is the user who's querying Watchman also the same user who started the Watchman daemon? Everything should work if so.

I'd check the assumption that the socket is called `sock!` with an exclamation mark. I'm pretty sure the exclamation mark was in the error message as punctuation, not because it is part of the socket's path.

It might help if you ran `watchman watch-diag` and linked a gist or pastebin so we can more easily see what's going on.

Comment: I'm sure glad to see your comment. `watchman watch-diag` also hit the same No such file or directory error. I'm not familiar with how daemons work, but I installed and started Watchman all from the same user. Is there something else I can try? See the edit above

Comment: Could you paste the output of `ps aux | grep 'watchman'` so we can see which user is running Watchman, and could you run `ls /usr/local/var/run/watchman` so we can see which watchman sockets exist?

Comment: I'm also interested in seeing the contents of `/var/facebook/watchman/learning-state/log`.